# Replacing character in JSON file with Python. Problem with editing due to big file (over 1 GB)

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a big JSON file (exported via Azure Data Factory). If DataFactory finds an issue it adds $ signs between objects. For example, it looks like this:

```
<br>{...}<br>
{...}<br>
{...}${...}<br>
```

So I have an error for example `json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 1 column 21994 (char 21993)`

I was dealing with it in an easy way - notepad++ replacing $ to \n and it was good ;) but now my file is about 1.3 GB and I didn't have a tool to edit such a big file.

I use python to export data from all JSON objects in the file and export them to XMLs.

Now I'm looking for some solution to replace all of the $ signs to newlines `\n` and clean the file.

The beginning of my code is:

```
a = open('test.json', 'r', encoding = 'UTF8')
data1 = a.readlines()
a.close()

for i in range(len(data1)):
    print('Done%d/%d'%(i,len(data1)))
    jsI = json.loads(data1[i])
```

and there if file occurs to $ sign it is over.

May I ask for some advice on how to replace $ signs with newlines in a file using Python?

Comment: Is this on a Windows, Mac, or Linux system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To be able to handle possible `$` characters in strings within JSON objects, you can split the input string `data1` with `$` into fragments, join the fragments into a string one by one until it is parsable as JSON, at which point you output the string and clear it to move on to the next fragment:

```
import json
candidate = ''
for fragment in data1.split('$'):
    candidate += fragment
    try:
        json.loads(candidate)
        print(candidate)
        candidate = ''
    except json.decoder.JSONDecodeError:
        candidate += '$'
        continue
```

Given `data1 = '''{}${"a":"$"}${"b":{"c":2}}'''`, for example, this outputs:

```
{}
{"a":"$"}
{"b":{"c":2}}
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is probably on `a.readlines()` because it brings the entire file to your memory. When dealing with huge files, it's way more interesting to read it line by line, like this:

```
with open(fname) as f: 
    for line in f:
        # Do your magic here, on this loop
# No need to close it, since the `with` will take care of that.
```

If your objective is to replace every `$` with a `\n`, it will be like this:

```
with open(fname, "r+") as f: 
    for line in f:
        line.replace("$", "\n")
```